# playing just the video from webpage using the url

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, url

i want to develop an android app . the app will use urls to play videos from various websites.
but the url isnt directly a url of any video. the url will open a webpage and that webpage contains so many links and contents including a video to be played on clicking "play" button.

is it possible i load the url by clicking a button from app and without loading the webview i just play the video from that webpage?

an example of url= https://something.to/watch/season-3/episode-1.html

can i play the episode-1.html from this url?

another url= https://something.com/watch/hacklegend-of-the-twilight/1

note: the urls i posted here are dummy urls

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: for playing video you need the uri of the video, the URL to where the actual file is saved in the server

Comment: so it isnt possible to get the video without actual location of that video in server? i dont have any knowledge about server and webpage structure , but i think the actual location of the video is somewhere in the html sectio. can we get it?